# thumbnails are not properly shown in light box gallery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, lightbox

I have used light box 2 to create a gallery for my bootstrap 3 webpage.
The thumbnails are not properly arranged. It is supposed to seen as a horizontal line but it shows in a vertical line. Besides this, lightbox works properly. Below is my code.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Gallery</h3>        
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="row">
                <div class "col-lg-3">  
                    <a href="img/1.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class "col-lg-3">  
                    <a href="img/2.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class "col-lg-9">  
                    <a href="img/3.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class "col-lg-3">  
                    <a href="img/1.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class "col-lg-3">  
                    <a href="img/2.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class "col-lg-3">  
                    <a href="img/3.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                    </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am also attaching a screenshot of it:

[image: the thumbnails are supposed to line up horizentlly]

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid. Your are using `col-lg-3`, `col-lg-3` and `col-lg-9` for your first three columns. Now what does 3+3+9 equal …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your link to bootstrap, or the copy of bootstrap you are using is not valid. Perhaps the gallery is disabling or overriding its styles somehow. In either case it will work if you replace

```
 class="col-lg-2" // or the equivalent
```

with

```
 style="width:33%; display:inline-block"  // with the equivalent width
```

EXAMPLE:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stanford.edu/~nisham/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://xcounter.se/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
<h3>Gallery</h3>

        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="http://www.theintentionallife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="http://www.theintentionallife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="https://www.rome2rio.com/images/rome2rio-2.png" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="https://www.rome2rio.com/images/rome2rio-2.png" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d5967_046bf0297b2343ed87cf116a298746c3.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d5967_046bf0297b2343ed87cf116a298746c3.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="http://www.theintentionallife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="http://www.theintentionallife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="https://www.rome2rio.com/images/rome2rio-2.png" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="https://www.rome2rio.com/images/rome2rio-2.png" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
                <div style="width:33%; display:inline-block"> <a href="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d5967_046bf0297b2343ed87cf116a298746c3.jpg" data-title="caption" data-lightbox="school">
                        <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/6d5967_046bf0297b2343ed87cf116a298746c3.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                        </a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works well with your suggestion. Thank you so much.

Comment: it works well with your answer. thanks for the suggestion.